# Assuming signed overflow does not occur when simplifying multiplication

Tags: c, gcc

So there's this gcc warning that bothers me:

```
warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when simplifying multiplication
```

The code it points at looks like this:

```
/* Move the memory block of entries after the removed one - if any. */          
if (database->entries + database->entries_size - 1 != database_entry) {         
    memmove(                                                                    
        database_entry,                                                         
        database_entry + 1,                                                     
        sizeof(spm_database_entry_t)                                            
            * (                                                                 
                (database->entries + database->entries_size)                    
                - database_entry - 1                                            
            )                                                                   
    );                                                                          
}
```

As you can easily guess it moves part of the container's memory after element removal to allow its further reallocation (shrinking).

- `database_entry` is a pointer of type `spm_database_entry_t*` to the removed element
- `database->entries` is a pointer to array of `spm_database_entry_t`
- `database->entries_size` is a `size_t` representing number `database->entries` elements **before** the removal

How to get rid of the warning? Can I prevent the multiplication simplifying or maybe there's better way to calculate how much memory needs moving?

**edit**

**Are you sure that `database_entry < database->entries + database->entries_size`?**

Positive.

**What are the compiler flags you're using?**

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes
-Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wwrite-strings
-Winit-self -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wformat=2
-Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-unused-parameter
-Wuninitialized -Wold-style-definition -Wno-missing-braces
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum
-Wbad-function-cast -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Winline -Wundef -Wnested-externs
-Wunreachable-code -Wfloat-equal -Wredundant-decls
-pedantic -ansi
-fno-omit-frame-pointer -ffloat-store -fno-common -fstrict-aliasing
```

**edit2**

Casting to `unsigned int` before the multiplication seem to do the trick, but casting to `size_t` doesn't. I don't get it - standard says `size_t` is always unsigned...

**edit3**

If context can be of any use: https://github.com/msiedlarek/libspm/blob/master/libspm/database.c#L116

**edit4**

Solution based on steveha's answer:

```
/* Calculate how meny entries need moving after the removal. */                 
size_t entries_to_move = (                                                             
    (database->entries + database->entries_size)                                
    - database_entry - 1                                                        
);                                                                              

/* Move the memory block of entries after the removed one - if any. */          
memmove(                                                                        
    database_entry,                                                             
    database_entry + 1,                                                         
    sizeof(spm_database_entry_t) * entries_to_move                              
);
```

Comment: Are you sure `database->entries + database->entries_size - 1 > database_entry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I favor additional intermediate temporary variables.  The compiler will see that they are used for only the one calculation, and will optimize the variables away; but in a debug build, you can single-step, examine the variables, and make sure it really is doing what you expect.

```
/* Move the memory block of entries after the removed one - if any. */          
assert(database_entry >= database->entries &&
        database_entry < database->entries + database->entries_size);

size_t i_entry = database_entry - database->entries;
size_t count_to_move = (database->entries_size - 1) - i_entry;
size_t bytes_to_move = count_to_move * sizeof(spm_database_entry_t);
memmove(database_entry, database_entry + 1, bytes_to_move);
```

Most of the time, `bytes_to_move` will not be 0, but if it is 0 then `memmove()` will simply move 0 bytes and no harm done.  So we can remove that `if` statement, unless you had something else inside it that needs doing only when the move happens.

Also, if you do it this way, and you are still getting the warning, you will get a line number that will point you right at what the compiler is worried about.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, as creating additional variable `entries_to_move` of type `size_t` and then multiplying it by size of entry type is IMHO clean solution and actually solves the warning, so you certainly set me on a right track.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue relates to the fact that `size_t`, as returned by `sizeof(spm_database_entry_t)`, is always an unsigned type (usually just a type synonym for `unsigned int` or `unsigned long int`, if I remember correctly). There's a theoretical possibility, however, that if the value of `database_entry` exceeds `database->entries + database->entries_size` that you'll end up multiplying a signed quantity by an unsigned type, raising the possibility of bugs or integer overflows. Normally, when signed and unsigned types get mixed like this, the smaller type is cast/coerced into the larger type, or, if they're equally ranked, the signed type is coerced to an unsigned. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so it's difficult to suggest an improvement.

Comment: At the moment of `memmove` I'm sure that `database_entry` is in range of `database->entries`. The question I guess is how to tell that to the compiler.

Comment: @MikołajSiedlarek, if you're absolutely certain that overflow is an impossibility, then I believe you should be able to prevent the warning (and perhaps enable some compiler optimizations) by compiling with the `-fstrict-overflow` flag.

Comment: Preventing all set of warnings to get rid of one? Doesn't seem right. I like warnings, they're there for a reason.

Comment: @MikołajSiedlarek, well, it doesn't prevent all warnings, just a specific class of warning that pertain to signed integer overflow. If you don't think that's possible in your code, then it shouldn't cause any harm. On the other hand, if it is possible in your code and you choose to compile anyway, the warning isn't going to save you from bugs. I really doubt that manually casting to `unsigned int` is going to prevent any bugs from cropping up either, since `size_t` is most likely already defined to equal `unsigned int` through a `typedef`.

Comment: But somewhere else in my library (it's not this one `if` actually) I might do something stupid with integer overflow and I'd like the compiler to warn me. I'm only sure that this specific occurrence is false-positive.